Wix Velo backend call updateSecret does not work as intended
I need to store my API token (to be renewed every hour).
The following code throws the error:

PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied, status: 403"

I have setup Members Area, secret_id is correct value.
export function SaveTokenForAlto(secret_id, token_id){
 const secret = {
         value: token_id, 
          };
 return wixSecretsBackend
  .updateSecret(secret_id, secret)
  .then(() => {console.log("Secret  updated");})
  .catch((error) => {console.error(error);});}

It should update the secret value in the Wix secret manager.

Seems to be a bug. Use the v2 function instead with elevation:
import { secrets } from 'wix-secrets-backend.v2';
import {elevate} from 'wix-auth'

export function SaveTokenForAlto(secret_id, token_id) {
    const secret = {
        value: token_id,
    };

    const elevated = elevate(secrets.updateSecret)

    return elevated(secret_id, secret)
        .then(() => { console.log("Secret  updated"); })
        .catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
}

